# Windows Explorer: ignore empty folders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How can Windows Explorer be configured to ignore empty folders like found in git/github:

[image: Example].

If I clicked the highlighted folder here, it would skip past all of the folders that have no other files in them (skips folders `test` through `android`) to take me to the end folder that has multiple files.

Further example:

My folder structure is like this where every folder but the last one is empty and only contains another folder:

```
~\Images
~\Images\2010
~\Images\2010\SuperUser
~\Images\2010\SuperUser\Lobstw
~\Images\2010\SuperUser\Lobstw\Questions
~\Images\2010\SuperUser\Lobstw\Questions\thisquestion.txt
```

Clicking the `Images` folder should take me straight to `\Questions` because all of the parents of the Questions folder are empty. It stops at `Questions` because it has a file.

Comment: He is asking how to bypass all of the parent directories i believe, so you don't have to go through 12 folders to reach the desired file.

Comment: If you click on a displayed folder, you should go directly there.  It isn't clear what the question is asking.  I've never seen any file manager or browse function where you need to go individually through a nesting of folders to get to the displayed one.  Is the question how to have the file manager ignore the actual child folder collection in the current directory and instead display the first subdirectory levels that contain a file?

Comment: @fixer1234 As far as I understood your last point is what I'm after. I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: Windows Explorer can't do that (by itself). The desired behavior would be for Explorer to detect a directory containing nothing but another directory and enter the latter; until it arrives at a folder not containing only a single directory.

Comment: Not possible in Windows Explorer. Are other tools that Windows Explorer acceptable for you?

Comment: @miroxlav Yep, any tool that can do this (while being lightweight) would be fine, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows Explorer. As you indicated, you are open to alternative solutions so you can achieve this using [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) (although the tool is not free):

1. enter `~\Images\` directory
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Branch View) so all files from all subdirectories inside `~\Images\` are displayed as if they were directly in `~\Images\`
3. highlight the file `thisquestion.txt` (or any other desired file)
4. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again to switch back to normal directory view (of directory which contains the file you selected in step **3**)

So now you are in `~\Images\2010\SuperUser\Lobstw\Questions\`.